# like nm -D or readelf -s, list dynamic symbols with python ctypes?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, symbols, dynamic-library

is it possible implement `nm -D` or `readelf -s` using python ctypes?

I want to list all dynamic symbols of a `.so` file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Presumably you'll need to read the API at some point?

Comment: Hi, I just like to poke around `.so` libraries for fun.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is: **No**, it is highly unlikely that `ctypes` will give you the enumeration of all available symbols in a library.

Reasons for this are mainly in the scope of `ctypes` as a Python module, and the scope of dynamic library API's: POSIX [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html)+[`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) or Win32 [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)+[`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The primary task of these API's is to, well, load DLL's and obtain callable addresses by symbol names/ordinals. They are **not designed** for symbol enumeration. You can't list symbols using them; and CPython [relies on them](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c), off course, to implement its functions.

It is also needs to be explained that the `nm` and `readelf` tools you mentioned do **their own parsing** of executable files to get the symbols list. This is quite tangential to loading the library into memory as an executable module. So you will need a different Python module to do that, something like [`python-elf`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-elf/) for example.

Comment: so basically what `nm` does, is open the binary, read byte to byte, then print the collected results? I strace'ed `nm`, and found it's calling `libbfd`. Can we obtain dynamic symbols by calling libbfd using ctypes?

Comment: @est, yes, you are basically right. These tools read ELF files byte to byte, parse them, and then print out some of the gathered tables. `libbfd` is just a [binutils library](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), which does all the hard lifting for these tools. You could off course make up an interface to that library on top of `ctypes` using [libbfd API](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/bfd/), but it is very likely that this has been already done in a Python library like python-elf or something similar.

Comment: thanks! So it is possible to list all export functions of .so files with ctypes? Do you know something similar unde Windows?